# dynamically displaying data in text field ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

Hello guys i am trying attempt a dynamic select here. as soon as i select the customer his total value in the bill should come and get displayed in the text field tag.

the view

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".customerid").bind("change", function() { 

      var data = {
        customer_id: jQuery(".customerid :selected").val()  
      }
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "get_cust_bill",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'script',
        data: data
      });
    });
  });
</script>


 <div class ="customerid"><%= f.label :customer_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "-Select a Customer"}, :class => "state", :style=>'width:210px;'%></div><br />

     <div class ="customerbill">
      <%= f.label :total_value, "Total Value" %>
  <%= render :partial => "customerbill" %>
```

js.erb file

```
jQuery('.customerbill').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'customerbill') %>");
```

the customerbill partial

```
<% options = []
  options = @cust_bill.total_value if @cust_bill.present? %>
<%= text_field_tag "total_value", options %>
```

in contoller

```
def get_cust_bill
    @cust_bill = CustomerBill.find_all_by_customer_id(params[:customer_id]) if params[:customer_id]
  end
```

I feel the problem lies in the partial, the way i am calling the `options` so can anyone guide me how to get the value in text field??? thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was using getJSON method....and i feel that can be used here. hope the followng works.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
    jQuery(".customerid select").bind("change", function() {
          var data = {
            product_id: jQuery(this).val()  
          }
          jQuery.getJSON(
             "/controller_name/get_cust_bill",
            data,
            function(data){
          var result = "";
          res = parseFloat(a[1]);
           jQuery('.price input').val(res);
          });            
            });
        });
```

controller

```
def get_cust_bill
    @cust_bill = CustomerBill.find_all_by_customer_id(params[:customer_id]).map{|p| [p.price]} if params[:customer_id]
respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @cust_bill }
    end
  end
```

so no need of calling js. erb partial you can simply have

```
<div class = "price"><%= f.input :price, :label => 'Price', :input_html => { :size => 20} %></div><br/>
```

all the best :)

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, total_value text field does not show anything. Could you try to output the value of options and check if it always has a value? I suggest you check out the documentation for the [text_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag). Basically, it accepts three variables like this:

```
text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
```

Comment: Yeah i understood..thanks.. :) but now i dunno how to put total value in the text field tag...!! how do i do it???

Comment: Do you mean set it as the default for the text field? Doesn't setting the value attribute work?

Comment: i tried setting the value as @cust_bill.total_value but it seems it is not working.

Comment: Are you sure @cust_bill.total_value is not nil or empty? Because you're only checking if cust_bill.present? not if total_value is present. It's weird because text_field_tag :total_value, nil, :value => '10'" works for me. I suggest you check out cust_bill.total_value, try to print it and see what it returns.